# SQLITE - Using results from a subquery in same query

Tags: sqlite, eloquent

I would like to know if, and if yes, how I could accomplsh the following:

Lets say I have two tables:

Table A has two Columns: id, name

Table B columns: owner, argument

Now I am trying to find in table A all rows with specific name (animal) and use their ids to find it's argument value in table b. Those argument values are different ids in table a. So as a result I would like to get two columns. first has the id of the items who has the specific name (animal) I am looking for and second column has the name of the item which has the id that is argument of the initial ids.

table a (example)

```
id || name
1  || animal
2  || animal
3  || animal
4  || animal
15 || cat
16 || dog
17 || horse
18 || bird
...
```

table b (example)

```
owner  || argument
1      || 15
2      || 16
3      || 17
4      || 18
...
```

result (example)

```
id || name
1  || cat
2  || dog
3  || horse
4  || bird
```

Thanks in advance for any hints / help.

Andreas

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN` instead of a subquery? Please [edit] your post and show the SQL that you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double join from `tablea` to `tableb` and again `doublea`:

```
select 
  a.name ownwename, 
  t.name name
from tablea a
inner join tableb b
on b.owner = a.id
inner join tablea t
on t.id = b.argument 
where a.name = 'animal'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hR7GiMeBC29inUJkre6Vd/1)

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will do what you want

```
SELECT owner, name FROM tableb JOIN tablea ON argument = id;
```

However, as using a subquery you could use :-

```
SELECT owner, (SELECT name FROM tablea WHERE argument = id) AS name FROM tableb;
```

### Working Example :-

```
DROP TABLE If EXISTS tablea;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablea (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO tablea (name) VALUES ('animal'),('animal'),('animal'),('animal'),('cat'),('dog'),('horse'),('bird'),
('animal'),('cat'),('dog'),('horse'),('bird'),('animal'),
('cat'),('dog'),('horse'),('bird')    -- id's 15-18 inclusive
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableb (owner INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, argument INTEGER);
INSERT INTO tableb (argument) VALUES(15),(16),(17),(18);

SELECT owner, name FROM tableb JOIN tablea ON argument = id;
SELECT owner, (SELECT name FROM tablea WHERE argument = id) AS name FROM tableb;
```

### Results :-

[image]

and the second

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I made a fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hR7GiMeBC29inUJkre6Vd/0

But as result I want:

animal - cat | 
animal - dog | 
animal - horse | 
animal - bird

Comment: Then simple, use `SELECT owner, 'animal -'||name FROM tableb JOIN tablea ON argument = id;` (or likewise for the subquery).

Comment: If you want the result column name to be name then use SELECT owner, 'animal -'||name AS name FROM tableb JOIN tablea ON argument = id;

Comment: hmm, buti don't want the owner id. i want two columns: first name of tablea "animal" and second the name of id which is the argument. so: Animal - Cat  etc.

Comment: That's not what your question says as the expected result, the results above match the expected result other than column names. You need to be clear and precise as to what you want and you should edit the question accordingly or preferably ask another question.

Comment: Yeah, I initially said id, true. But with ur query I won't get the asked result. Can you please use my fiddle and ur query? I would not only get the rows with cat dog horse bird but also the others.